# Objective c: Add event to google calendar

Tags: ios, objective-c

I can not find much documentation on google's lib to add an event in google calendar.

With my research I wrote the code below:

```
GTLRCalendar_Event *newEvent = [[GTLRCalendar_Event alloc] init];

    newEvent.summary = @"Sample Added Event";
    newEvent.descriptionProperty = @"Description of sample added event";

    GTLRDateTime *startDateTime = [GTLRDateTime dateTimeWithDate:pickUpDate offsetMinutes:0];
    GTLRCalendar_EventDateTime *startEventDateTime = [[GTLRCalendar_EventDateTime alloc] init];
    startEventDateTime.dateTime = startDateTime;
    newEvent.start = startEventDateTime;

    GTLRDateTime *endDateTime = [GTLRDateTime dateTimeWithDate:pickUpDate offsetMinutes:60];
    GTLRCalendar_EventDateTime *endEventDateTime = [[GTLRCalendar_EventDateTime alloc] init];
    endEventDateTime.dateTime = endDateTime;
    newEvent.end = endEventDateTime;

    GTLRCalendarService *service = [[GTLRCalendarService alloc] init];

    GTLRCalendarQuery_EventsInsert *query = [GTLRCalendarQuery_EventsInsert queryWithObject:newEvent calendarId:@"primary"];

    [service executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLRServiceTicket *callbackTicket, id object, NSError *callbackError) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@",[callbackError localizedDescription]);

    }];
```

I get error Login required, how do I login? It is the user who must login? There is not a lot of documentation on the web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at [EventKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/ekevent) and let the user syncs the calendar by himself.

Otherwise, some steps about the Google Calendar API are described [here](https://blog.hipolabs.com/how-to-use-the-google-calendar-api-on-ios-563ad3abb006)